# How to get correctly-encoded HTML from the clipboard?

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, clipboard

Has anyone noticed that if you retrieve HTML from the clipboard, it gets the encoding wrong and injects weird characters?

For example, executing a command like this:

```
string s = (string) Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Html)
```

Results in stuff like:

```
<FONT size=-2>Â Â <A href="/advanced_search?hl=en">Advanced 
Search</A><BR>Â Â <A href="/preferences?hl=en">Preferences</A><BR>Â Â <A 
href="/language_tools?hl=en">Language 
Tools</A></FONT>
```

*Not sure how MarkDown will process this, but there are weird characters in the resulting markup above.*

It appears that the bug is with the .NET framework.  What do you think is the best way to get correctly-encoded HTML from the clipboard?

Answer (score 3):

In this case it is not so visible as it was in my case. Today I tried to copy data from clipboard but there were a few unicode characters. The data I got were as if I would read a UTF-8 encoded file in Windows-1250 encoding *(local encoding in my Windows)*.

It seems you case is the same. If you save the html data *(remember to put non-breakable space = 0xa0 after the Â character, not a standard space)* in Windows-1252 *(or Windows-1250; both works)*. Then open this file as a UTF-8 file and you will see what there should be.

For my other project I made a function that fix data with corrupted encoding.

In this case simple conversion should be sufficient:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text);
text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

My original function is a little bit more complex and contains tests to ensure that data are not corrupted...

```
public static bool FixMisencodedUTF8(ref string text, Encoding encoding)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    return false;
  byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(text);
  // there should not be any character outside source encoding
  string newStr = encoding.GetString(data);
  if (!string.Equals(text, newStr)) // if there is any character "outside"
    return false; // leave, the input is in a different encoding
  if (IsValidUtf8(data) == 0) // test data to be valid UTF-8 byte sequence
    return false; // if not, can not convert to UTF-8
  text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
  return true;
}
```

I know that this is not the best *(or correct solution)* but I did not found any other way how to fix the input...

**EDIT**: *(July 20, 2017)*

It Seems like the Microsoft already found this error and now it works correctly. I'm not sure whether the problem is in some frameworks, but I know for sure, that now the application uses a different framework as in time, when I wrote the answer. *(Now it is 4.5; the previous version was 2.0)*
*(Now all my code fails in parsing the data. There is another problem to determine the correct behaviour for application with fix already aplied and without fix.)*

Answer (score 1):

You have to interpret the data as UTF-8.  See [MS Office hyperlinks change code page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189640/ms-office-hyperlinks-change-code-page).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText(System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat.Html);
```

Answer (score 1):

**DataFormats.Html** [specification](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) states it's encoded in UTF-8. But there's a bug in .NET 4 Framework and lower, and it actually reads as UTF-8 as **Windows-1252**.

You get allot of wrong encodings, leading funny/bad characters such as 
'Å','â€¹','Å’','Å½','Å¡','Å“','Å¾','Å¸','Â','Â¡','Â¢','Â£','Â¤','Â¥','Â¦','Â§','Â¨','Â©'

Full explanation here
[Debugging Chart Mapping Windows-1252 Characters to UTF-8 Bytes to Latin-1 Characters](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html)

Soln: Create a translation dictionary and search and replace.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your original source document is, but be aware that Word and Outlook provide several versions of the clipboard in different encodings. One is usually Windows-1252 and another is UTF-8. Possibly you're grabbing the UTF-8 encoded version by default, when you're expecting the Windows-1252 (Latin-1 + Smart Quotes)? Non-ASCII characters would show up as multiple odd Latin-1 accented characters. Most "Smart Quotes" are not in the Latin-1 set and are often three bytes in UTF-8.

Can you specify which encoding you want the clipboard contents in?